# Extract average values from one dataset using dates from another dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two datasets - one (let's say df1) which has incubation start and end dates for each nest and another dataset that has hourly temperature data (let's say df2).

I want to get the average temperature data from df2 using the date range for each nest in df1. How do I do this in R?

dput() of first 5 row of df1 looks like this:

```
structure(list(Nest.no = c("1", "4", "5", "10", "11"), Start = c("12-02-2009", 
"19-02-2009", "15-03-2009", "15-04-2009", "17-04-2009"), End = c("03-04-2009", 
"10-04-2009", "04-05-2009", "04-06-2009", "06-06-2009")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

dput() of first 5 row of df2 looks like this:

```
structure(list(Nesting.season = c("2009 -2010", "2009 -2010", 
"2009 -2010", "2009 -2010", "2009 -2010"), Date = c("04-01-2010", 
"04-01-2010", "04-01-2010", "04-01-2010", "05-01-2010"), Temperature = c(23.773, 
27.764, 24.448, 23.966, 23.869)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(df1)` and same for `df2` instead of a screenshot of your data.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the suggestion. Edited my question to provide the output of first 5 rows of both the datasets.

Comment: Thank you. Given what you provided, what would the desired output look like? The dates in `df2` don't fall in the cases in `df1`.

Comment: Hi. The dates in df1 show the start and end date of incubation for each nest. But df2 has hourly temperature data. The desired output would have a new column of average temperature data extracted from df2 based on start and end dates from df1.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df2 |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date))

df1 |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(across(c(Start, End), dmy),
    df2 = list(as_tibble(df2)),
    temp = pmap_dbl(list(df2, Start, End), function(df, startdate, enddate) {
      filter(df, Date >= startdate, Date <= enddate) |> 
        summarize(Temperature = mean(Temperature)) |> 
        pull(Temperature)
    }
    )
  )

# A tibble: 5 × 5
  Nest.no Start      End        df2               temp
  <chr>   <date>     <date>     <list>           <dbl>
1 1       2009-02-12 2009-04-03 <tibble [5 × 3]>   NaN
2 4       2009-02-19 2009-04-10 <tibble [5 × 3]>   NaN
3 5       2009-03-15 2009-05-04 <tibble [5 × 3]>   NaN
4 10      2009-04-15 2009-06-04 <tibble [5 × 3]>   NaN
5 11      2009-04-17 2009-06-06 <tibble [5 × 3]>   NaN
```

However, since none of the dates in the two dataframes overlap, no temperatures get returned.